# Foreach controller not working for Json data

Tags: foreach, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, foreach-loop-container

I have below json

```
[
  {
   "id":  13059,
   "xid": "81f4278a53fe4c1a8d03346a34d76a47",
   "yid": "8cbefbadec52ced5:e4f6801:17c73aeaf21:-5a75"
  },
  {
    "id":  13059,
    "xid": "061ef5792e8f4603bb1f86c71e6fb16c",
    "yid": "8cbefbadec52ced5:e4f6801:17c73aeaf21:-5a56"
  },
  {
    "id":  13061,
    "xid": "4290987b25b34ffbb5b0329f1ab1b673",
    "yid": "8cbefbadec52ced5:e4f6801:17c73aeaf21:-5dd4"
  },
  {
    "id":  13063,
    "xid": "57c4a2790aa44376be1e5215c5cb7ad0",
    "yid": "8cbefbadec52ced5:e4f6801:17c73aeaf21:-585e"
  }
]
```

Now I put the above json in global variable in JSR223 sampler

```
 vars.put("jsonVariable",JSON.stringify(aboveJson))
```

Now next I add "ForEach Controller" and add

```
   InputVariable Prefix = jsonVariable

   Output variable name = outVariable
```

Then I add another JSR223 sampler inside ForEach Controller and log below data

```
log.info(${outVariable})
```

But ForEach controller is not even executing for once. Please let me know where I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForEach Controller isn't smart enough to parse your JSON structure, it iterates an individual set of [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which looks like:

```
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
etc.
```

so depending on what you're trying to achieve you need to:

1. In case if you want individual values of `id`, `xid` and/or `yid` - add 1 or more [JSON Extractors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) and configure them to fetch the values from the response. Then use ForEach Controller and feed the variable from JSON Extractor to it

   [image]
2. If you want to iterate JSON Objects instead you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) code:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).eachWithIndex { entry, int index ->
       vars.put('json_' + (index + 1), new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(entry).toString())
   }
   ```

   [image]

Comment: In Treeview the data in JSR223 sampler(inside foreach loop) request is showing correct but when I use log.info('${json}'); inside JSR223 sampler then the output in logs show only 1 value repeated multiple times

Comment: Don't inline [JMeter functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, only first occurrence will be cached and used for subsequent iterations, use `log.info(vars.get('json'))` instead. More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy)

Comment: I am using log.info('${json}'); using javascript in JSR223. This log.info(vars.get('json')) is not working there