# How to access data inside foreach controller Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, counter, jmeter-5.0, jsr223, foreach-loop-container

How to access data inside foreach controller using JSR223 sampler with index value. For example

```
 data_1 = something

 data_2 = something
```

etc.

Whenever I tried using counter, it gives only data_1 for every count but in treeview I see that counter is working properly. How can I access every item in foreach controller.

Answer (score 0):

What "data" do you want to access?

If you configure [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) like:

[image]

then you will be able to get the current value of `foo` variable as:

```
vars.get('foo')
```

Current iteration of the ForEach Controller can be accessed as:

```
vars.get('__jm__your-foreach-controller-name-here__idx')
```

if you haven't changed the default name it would be:

```
vars.get('__jm__ForEach Controller__idx')
```

Where `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more details on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands.

Answer (score 0):

Jus for you reference, I have completed my task as mentioned in below URL (which is my question) using  approach 2.

[Foreach controller not working for Json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74066660/foreach-controller-not-working-for-json-data/74067025?noredirect=1#comment130777418_74067025)

Now I am able to get every each json object inside the json array using foreach controller. Now here is the issue, when I log.info(json), I get the same data very time but there are other data as well which can only be seen in treeview.

I dont understand that how do I access all the data.